# How to login outside and call HTTP methods there in Meteor?

Tags: http, session, meteor

I want to login outside site from the server or client using Meteor. After logged in, I want to save that session, so that I will be able to call GET/POST HTTP methods.

Is there any way to do it using HTTP package in Meteor?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've done this in Python (using "requests" library). But in Meteor HTTP package there is no "session" stuff as in requests. Sending current cookies to the next session doesn't help